# Svg animations replaying in the same spot

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, path

I am working on a tower defense game with HTML, CSS, and JS. I want to be able to create svg circles that will follow a path using an svg animation. In order to do this, I wrote this code:

```html
<div id="trackPart">
  <progress id="healthBar" max="200" value="200" onclick="this.value = randInt(0, this.max)" ></progress>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 1000 3000" id="track" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="15" d="M 0, 50 h 900 v 100 h -800 v 100 h 800 v 300 h -900" style="cursor: pointer"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

```js
var path = document.getElementById("path")
var svgurl = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
var svg = document.getElementById("track")

listOfColors = ["green", "blue", "purple", "lime", "yellow"]

function attackerSVG(color) {
  let element = document.createElementNS(svgurl, "circle")
  element.setAttribute("cx", 0)
  element.setAttribute("cy", 0)
  element.setAttribute("r", 15)
  element.setAttribute("fill", color)

  let animation = document.createElementNS(svgurl, "animateMotion")
  animation.setAttribute("dur", "30s")
  animation.setAttribute("repeatCount", "indefinite")
  animation.setAttribute("rotate", "auto")
  animation.setAttribute("path", String(path.getAttribute("d")))
  animation.setAttribute("onrepeat", "console.log(\"repeat\")")
  animation.setAttribute("restart", "always")
  animation.beginElement()

  element.appendChild(animation)
  svg.appendChild(element)
  return element
}

attackerSVG("black")
```

The first time I run the attackerSvg function, everything works fine. A circle is created at the start of the path and follows it. However, once I create another one, it starts its animation sequence where the other svg circles are. If you want to see what I mean, you can go here
https://replit.com/@hello1964/Tower-defense-game#script.js

Whenever you see the circle change color, it's a new circle being created. When you look in the console it will print "repeat" every time a circle finishes a cycle. Since they are all in the same spot, it will print it multiple times. I would really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG maintain their own timings. Adding an element to the SVG, will start it at the current clock. To do what you want, you actually need to delay the start

```js
// outside globally somwhere
let count = 0;

// inside function attackerSVG
animation.setAttribute('begin', `${++count}s`)
```